# php jquery-load more data inside a loop

Tags: php, jquery

I have the posts inside a while and post replays inside another while
I want to add a load more link or button for replays.
I have this codes but just first load more works:

```
 <style>    #myList li{ display:none;list-style: none;}</style>

<?php $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbace");
$psql="SELECT * FROM tbl_users_posts limit 20";
    $qry=mysqli_query($conn,$psql);?>
<ul id="myList">
    <?php while($fql=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    $pst=$fql['post'];
    $pid=$fql['id'];
        echo $pid." ".$pst;?><br>


<?php $rpql="SELECT * FROM re_pst WHERE subid='$pid'";
    $qrep=mysqli_query($conn,$rpql);
    while($qrw=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qrep)){
        $remsg=$qrw['remsg'];?>
 <li>
     <?php echo $remsg;?><br>                       
<?php }?><br><br>
    </li>
<div id="loadMore">load more</div>
<?php }?>
</ul>
```

and the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jqmin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   size_li = $("#myList li").size();
    x=3;
    $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    $('#loadMore').click(function () {
        x= (x+2 <= size_li) ? x+2 : size_li;
        $('#myList li:lt('+x+')').show();
    });
 });
</script>
```

How can I fix that?
Thanks

Can I do it somehow by give number to posts and jquery command? some thing like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < X; $i++) {
```

Comment: Is it possible at all?

Comment: Generally, a load more button would fetch additional posts from the server using ajax rather than just showing hidden ones, why not research that approach instead ?

Comment: Tanks, this is more logical. you can explain a little. what to look for?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to you using id attribute for event. The value of id attribute must be unique. Instead of you can use class attribute.

The following code may be solution:

```
$('.loadMore').on('click', function(){
       $(this).parent('li').show();
})
```

Can you try using "loadMore" button by class attribute with above code?

Comment: with id just first -load more- works and with class all works but it shows the answers from the first post, respectively